# Rails app in docker returns database does not exists after successfully running rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I'm dockerizing the app I've been working on, but there's something I've been scratching my head trying out to figure out the reason why.

After the database is successfully created with

`docker-compose run web rake db:create`

```
Created database 'db_dev'
Created database 'db_test'
```

When I try to run the migration command

`docker-compose run web rake db:migrate`

It returns

```
database "db_dev" does not exist
```

If the command is executed again, the migration will be performed.

What could be the reason?

Here is my docker-compose.yml config

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.7
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=the_password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - the_net
  web:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    build: .
    image: the_app:latest
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=the_password
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - the_net
volumes:
  data:
networks:
  the_net:
    external: true
    name: the_net
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to setting the network, I was able to resolve this inconsistency by adding a link to the database service following the docker documentation

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

I can't fully grasp what was going, but my hypothesis is the docker container was communicating with a different database connection or instance  when the docker-compose run was being executed.